# Update progressbar from thread- MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, thread-safety

I am new to MVVM pattern. I have a problem updating progressbar from another thread.

> View.Xaml

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}">
```

> ViewModel.cs

```
public int ProgressBarValue 
{
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
            set
            {
                this.status = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ProgressBarValue);
            }
}


Thread th;

private void OnOk()
{
   th=new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartProcess));
}

private void StartProcess()
{
  utilityclass.DoWork();
}
```

> UtilityClass.cs

```
public void DoWork()
{
   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
      //dosomething
   }
}
```

My question is how can update the progress on DoWork method to the view ? I found many solutions by using background worker class. But for some reasons i cannot follow those methods. I really need a help here.

Comment: You can use `Dispatcher` to send information to MainUI Thread.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal do you have any examples.If so please share.

Comment: "But for some reasons i cannot follow those methods." - What are those reasons, and what methods did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply add `ProgressChanged` event in to `UtilityClass`.

```
class UtilityClass
{
    public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventHandler> ProgressChanged;

    public class ProgressChangedEventHandler : EventArgs
    {
        public int Progress
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public ProgressChangedEventHandler(int progress)
        {
            Progress = progress;
        }
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);

            if (ProgressChanged != null)
                ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventHandler(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to this event in your View Model and update property value each time when event is raised.

```
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        utilityclass = new UtilityClass();
        utilityclass.ProgressChanged += utilityclass_ProgressChanged;
    }

    void utilityclass_ProgressChanged(object sender, UtilityClass.ProgressChangedEventHandler e)
    {
        ProgressBarValue = e.Progress;
    }
```

Oh, and note that you should actually start the thread! And I assume that this method might need to be public.

```
    public void OnOk()
    {
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartProcess));
        th.Start();
    }
```

Also you might want to abort this thread when user closing the form.

This code will depend on your MVVM framework. Here I am using View Model derived from Caliburn.Micro's `Screen` class, so I can override `OnDeactivate` method and shut down thread there.

```
    protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
    {
        if (close)
        {
            th.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in comments, you should use `Dispatcher` to updated ui-bound values.

In your method DoWork you should call appropriate `Dispatcher` of the Ui components to invoke update process in UI-thread. Since you use MVVM, your ViewModel shouldn't know anything about UI components, so you can use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => { ProgressBarValue = i; } );
```

This will update your progressBar.

Also, have a look at more common INotifyPropertyChanged implementations like one from ReSharper with value checking for being really changed.

Comment: My Utilityclass cannot access ProgressBarvalue property because it is another class. Then how can i use the above method.

Comment: How were you going to update progressbar at first? You may want to make property accessible, you might want to pass some update callback into DoWork. There are plenty of ways to that, including your worker firing events, and your vm subscribed to them, it's up to you. There are tons of examples on the net, like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo)